How to prevent auto page adding in PDFKit
I'm using PDFKit in nodejs. When you add some content (images, in my case) that overflows the page it's added on, pdfkit will automatically add a new page. I need to prevent that, and I couldn't find how to do it. Another way would be to remove the added page, but here again, I couldn't find how to remove a page with PDFKit. Any ideas?
I searched the docs, studied the source code, but couldn't find anything.

I can't speak to how to do this with just PDFKit, but I have used canvas2pdf, which is a wrapper for PDFKit:
import fs from 'fs'
import canvas2pdf from 'canvas2pdf'

let image = // create Image somehow...
let file = fs.createWriteStream( outfilename );
let ctx = new canvas2pdf.PdfContext( file, { size: [800, 600] } );

ctx.stream.on( 'error', function( error ) {
    console.error( error );
    reject();
} );

ctx.stream.on( 'finish', function () {
    file.end();
    resolve();
} );

// I can use either of these methods to draw an image in the PDF
ctx.drawImage( image, 0, 0 );
ctx.doc.image( image.src, 0, 0 );
ctx.end();

example result
(note that it looks like canvas2pdf has been deprecated in favor of node-canvas)

Though I won't be able to use your solution in my specific case, I thank you and I'll remember node-canvas. :)
